# How to drop row from pandas data frame containing nan

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on python 3.x.I have a pandas data frame with only one column, student.At 501th row student contains `nan`
`df.at[501,'student']` returns `nan`
To remove this I used following code

```
df.at['student'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

But after that I'm still getting `nan` for `df.at[501,'student']`
I also tried this

```
df.at['student'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

But I'm using df in for loop to check value of student to apply some business logic but with `inplace=True` I'm getting `key error :501`
Can you suggest me how do I remove the `nan` & use df in for loop to check student value?

Comment: No It's not working. I have empty row in object data type column & other rows of the column contains text values. But the post you referred contains `NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another answer since it's completely a different case.
I think you are not looping correctly on the dataframe, seems like you are looping relying on the index of the dataframe when you should probably loop on the items row by row or preferably use `df.apply`.
If you still want to loop on the items and you don't care about the previous index, you can reset the index with `df.reset_index(drop=True)`

```py
df['student'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
df['student'].dropna(inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
# do your loop here
```

your problem is that you are dropping the item at index `501` then trying to access it, when you drop items pandas doesn't automatically update the index.

Answer (score 0):

the `replace` function that you use would replace the first parameter with the second.
if you want to replace the `np.nan` with empty then you have to do

```py
df['student'].replace(np.nan, '', inplace=True)
```

but this would not remove the row, it'd just replace it with an empty string, what you want is

```py
df['student'].dropna(inplace=True)
```

but you gotta do this before looping over the elements, don't `dropna` in the loop.

it'd be helpful to know what exactly you are doing in the loop

Comment: Hi It's not np.nan. Row is empty for sting type column. So I introduced np.nan to remove the `NaN` using `df['student'].dropna(inplace=True)`. But while I'm running the for loop I'm getting keyerror at `df.at[501,'student']`

Comment: @newinPython would you mind sharing the for loop that you are using ?

Comment: Sorry I can't able to provide the loop it contains business logic

Comment: @newinPython you don't have to provide the business logic, but without knowing how you are looping and where you are getting the error I can't figure out what you need

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove the rows that contains Nan values in the "student" column is

```py
df = df[~df['student'].isnull()]
```

Comment: After doing this step while I'm trying `df.at[501,'student']` again I'm getting `keyerror`